# enter total values of year in end of year

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add total values of year when end of the year. My MySQL query is OK, but my  function for identification of end of year is in error. Can you help me improve my query?

```
if ($day== date(strtotime("-12-31")) {
    $query1=mysql_query($sql1) 
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "total values"?

Comment: What's the value of `$day`?

Comment: @Jack $day== final day of the year

Comment: @Pekka웃 total of the year e.g  rainfall total values

Comment: Do you want to check last day of year condition ?

Answer (score 2):

[strtotime](https://www.php.net/strtotime) is very flexible. Be careful about timezone.
you can get the last day of the year as follows.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of december'));
```

Quote from manual.

> Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a
> time zone is specified in that parameter. Be careful not to use
> different time zones in each parameter unless that is intended. See
> date_default_timezone_get() on the various ways to define the default
> time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the current year.

```
if ($day == strtotime(date("Y")."-12-31")) {
    $query1=mysql_query($sql1) 
}
```